# 1k gamesanalysis (PGN)

Tags: analysis, pgn, database

I've been playing chess on-line for about 7 years now. I've downloaded my past games since 2011, its about 1k chess games. The download is in PGN format. Now I want to do an analyses on the data.

Is there a way to analyze all these games on-line or off-line, payed of free?

I'm interested in: The repeated mistakes to learn from, Personalized tips/hints, Statistics, learning curve (move rating, statistics).

Thanks for the info.

Comment: Why don't you start by posting your games here, **one at a time**? You do not have to post all 1k, but rather the ones you think illustrate your flaws the best. Just a thought. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there's a starving master (redundant, I know) who would analyze your games for money. The Chess Life magazine used to have (still has?) classified where these services were offered.  This is surely the most personalized way.

Many free chess engines will analyze your games.  They play at the 3200+ (USCF) now so they should be somewhat better than what you can do in most cases. I use Stockfish and SCID but I have to say I find SCID to be clunky.

You may find a two-pronged approach better.  Get master analysis. While that's in progress, chew through the games using an engine.